# Drawing Queried Geometry using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry, query

I am new to all of coding and I have a rest point with all of my park polygons, what I want to do is be able to  select a park  name from a drop down menu and query out and display the single park that is chosen. I believe I have everything set up to query my geometry, now I don't know how to get it to draw the queried feature. right now I have 2 different drop downs. According to my professor i have the selection stored in "selectedParkFeature" variable, and all I have to do now is to draw it on the map. I have researched and I am stuck. I am doing all of this on ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.17.

```
    query("#selectParkName").on('change', function (evt) { 
    var tempParkName = evt.target.value;
    getParkFeature(tempParkName);
});


//function to select the park
function getParkFeature(in_park_name) {
    var query = new Query();
    query.where = "NAME='" + in_park_name + "'";
    query.outFields = ["*"];          
    park.queryFeatures(query, function (featureSet) {
        console.log(featureSet);
        selectedParkFeature = featureSet.features[0];  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your function:

```
//function to select the park
function getParkFeature(in_park_name) {
    var sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
      new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,
      new Color([255,0,0]), 2),new Color([255,255,0,0.25])
    );
    var query = new Query();
    query.where = "NAME='" + in_park_name + "'";
    query.outFields = ["*"];          
    park.queryFeatures(query, function (featureSet) {
        console.log(featureSet);
        selectedParkFeature = featureSet.features[0];
        map.graphics.add(new Graphic(selectedParkFeature.geometry, sfs));  
    });
}
```

Comment: i changed it as is shown in your post, but it still will not draw. am I missing anything?